# Disabled UIButton dependant on 4 UITextFields

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I have 4 UITextFields that I am using to keep 2 UIButtons disabled until all 4 fields have data entered into them. I have the following code so far

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


if (([brand.text length] >0) && ([qty.text length] >0) && ([size.text length] >0) && ([price.text length] >0)) {
    [calcOneButton setEnabled:YES];
    [calcTwoButton setEnabled:YES];

}else {

}


}
```

I have a number of problems with this :-

1. When data is removed from the fields the UIButtons are still enabled
2. The Buttons arent enabling correctly, after I have entered data into all 4 fields I need to re-tap on a field to enable the button.
3. I am logging the length of each field but as a character is entered it starts at a count of 0 not 1.

Can anyone help with these points?

The code for logging the length of a field is as follows :-

```
#define MAXLENGTH 5
#define MAXQTY 3
#define MAXSIZE 4
#define MAXBRAND 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
if (textField == brand) {
    int lengtha = [brand.text length] ;
    NSLog(@"lenghta = %d",lengtha);
    if (lengtha >= MAXBRAND && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        brand.text = [brand.text substringToIndex:MAXBRAND];
        return NO;
    }
```

it follows the same format for all 4 fields, but as I enter a character the NSlog results as a 0 then 1 for the second character and so on.

Comment: Have you setup textFieldDidEndEditing: as this will help you in conjunction with the method you have already posted above. If you want to log the length of each field, is it perhaps one frame behind updating or does 1 character always get logged as 0? If so, you could just override it for now when you return the length.

Comment: @Krypton the code for the logging of field lengths is as follows `#define MAXLENGTH 5
#define MAXQTY 3
#define MAXSIZE 4
#define MAXBRAND 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 if (textField == brand) {
        int lengtha = [brand.text length] ;
        NSLog(@"lenghta = %d",lengtha);
        if (lengtha >= MAXBRAND && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            brand.text = [brand.text substringToIndex:MAXBRAND];
            return NO;
        }
`

Comment: Could you copy that out and paste it as an edit in your question? Very hard to see with zero formatting.

Comment: @Krypton I have added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another delegate-method.

Either use: `textFieldDidEndEditing:` like Krypton told you in a comment

or use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` for enable/disable directly when typing.

```
textField:(UITextField*)aTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange) aRange replacementString:(NSString*)aRepString
{
    NSString *newStr = [aTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:aRange withString:aRepString];
    if([newStr length]>0 && /*otherStringLength > 0*/)
          //enable
    else
          //disable
    return YES;
 }
```

But I think the most common way is to use the `didEndEditing`-method

Comment: does 

`if (([brand.text length] ==0) || ([qty.text length] ==0) || ([size.text length] ==0) || ([price.text length] ==0))`

look ok, I assuming I will need to use OR rather than AND

Comment: you only have to take into consideration that `shouldChangeCharatersInRange:`is called **before** the changes are made in the textfield. `length1>0 && length2>0 && ... => enable` is the same as `length1==0 || length2==0 || ... => disable`

Comment: yes that is now my problem, after the last textField has data entered and I tap on one of the buttons I notice that `didEndEditing` has not been called, how can i get this to call everytime?

Comment: I suppose the didEndEditing is not called because the firstResponder is not resigned. Either I would disable the buttons while the keyboard is open (on Return you can resign the firstResponder) and `didEndEditing:` will be called  or  you force the user to Return because the buttons are hidden by the keyboard  or  do your enable/disable-stuff in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. The last approach would be able to enable/disable the buttons while typing. Hope that helped...